# Getting money paid to a US based bank account for Indian company based invoice

Tags: united-states, income-tax, india, bank-account

I work for an american company and I used to get paid before directly by check. But now, I am raising invoices (for the work I do) from my Indian company. Is it ok if the USA company pays the Indian invoice to my USA located Chase bank ? Should I pay any taxes in USA for these Indian invoice payments sent to my USA based account ? Also, is it ok if the money is sent to the USA based bank account for an invoice from a foreign company ?

Comment: where are **you**?

Comment: @littleadv Right now in USA. But in the next few months will be in India.

Comment: So "Right now" the only relevant part of information is that you're in the USA. Why have you omitted that in your question?

Answer (score 1):

The data provided in your question is irrelevant. The data that you provided in the comments (that you're physically present in the US while doing the work) is the only relevant information needed to answer your question.

You will need to pay taxes in the US for the earnings. The company invoicing the US client will also need to pay taxes in the US for its earnings from these invoices.

You can transfer between bank accounts and deposit whatever you want anywhere you want, no-one cares (with respect to the US taxes, check with Indian tax accountant about Indian requirements).

Comment: The member whose comments I deleted was not the OP.